# Can we make folder inside template package of SpringBoot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have been working on dummy Web application, and there are lot html file in template which I want to organize. I am getting an error when I have keeping them in folder inside Templete, what is the procedure for that?

I am using thymleaf and SpringBoot for my application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call those templates in sub-folders?
Should be like this:

```java
@RequestMapping("/endpoint")
public String getMyPageItem() {
    return "my-folder/folder/item";
}
```

where `my-folder` inside `/resources/templates/` and `item` is `item.html` file

Comment: hi, thanks, that is working for me now.

Comment: @ANKURSHUKLA mind accepting answer please :)